# Understanding how these floating point numbers work?

Tags: floating-point, theory

I'm having a little difficulty understanding how floating point numbers work. Specifically in the following representations below (correct my mistakes):

1. Representing 0: this is represented by a full 0 bits in the exponent bits (8 in single precision and 11 in double precision). If I have all zeros in the exponent bits, will I still be able to represent zero even if my mantissa is not all zero?
2. Wikipedia shows that zero is represented by (−1)signbit×2^{−126}× 0.significandbits Why is it 2^{-126} when the lowest exponent value we can reach is 2^{-127} instead?
3. Representing denormal numbers: I suppose denormal numbers are represented as this format as well: (−1)signbit×2^{−126}× 0.significandbits. They are used to represent values lower than the smallest normal number. I'm guessing this is 2^{-127}, but if the representation for denormal numbers is as such, wouldn't denormal numbers still represent larger values than normal ones?
4. normalised numbers: (−1)signbit×2^{exponentbits−127}× 1.significandbits. I'm supposing the actual representation of the exponentbits is in terms of 0 to 255, as they don't represent in two complements form.
5. plus/minus infinity represented by a full 1 bits in the exponent bits. Again, does a non-zero mantissa matter if we use this representation to signify infinity?

Comment: I do not understand why you would think “wouldn't denormal numbers still represent larger values than normal ones?” Can you give an example of a (positive) subnormal number that would be greater than a (positive) normal number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per IEEE 754-2008:

- **NaN:** If the exponent field is all ones and the significand field is not zero, the floating-point datum is a NaN, regardless of the sign field. Preferably, a QNaN has the leading bit of the significand field 1 and a signaling NaN has 0, but this is not required.
- **Infinite:** If the exponent field is all ones and the significand field is zero, the datum is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • ∞, where *s* is the sign field. (*I.e.*, +∞ if the sign is 0 and −∞ if the sign is 1.)
- **Normal:** If the exponent field is neither all zeros nor all ones, the datum is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • (1 + *f* • 2<sup>−*q*</sup>) • 2<sup>*e* - *bias*</sup>, where *s* is the sign field, *f* is the significand field, *q* is the number of bits in the significand field, *e* is the exponent field, and *bias* is the exponent bias (127 for 32-bit floating-point).
- **Subnormal:** If the exponent field is all zeros, and the significand field is not, the datum is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • (0 + *f* • 2<sup>−*q*</sup>) • 2<sup>1 - *bias*</sup>. Note the two differences from normal: 0 is added to the significand instead of 1, and 1 is used for the exponent (before subtracting *bias*). This means subnormals have the same exponent as the smallest normals but are decreased by reducing the significand.
- **Zero:** If the exponent field is all zeroes, and the significand field is also all zeros, the datum is (−1)<sup>*s*</sup> • 0. (Note that IEEE 754 distinguishes +0 and −0.)

The exponent used with subnormals is 1 rather than 0 so that the numbers change from (normal) 1.000…000•2<sup>1−127</sup> to (subnormal) 0.111…111•2<sup>1−127</sup>. If 0 were used, there would be a jump to 0.0111…1111•2<sup>1−127</sup>.

The formula for the values of subnormals works for zeros too. So zeros do not actually need to be listed separately above.

Comment: can u give an example, for denormalized number @EricPostpischil. For example, when we use scientific notation we already make it "1.xxx" (start with 1 with moving left or right part, right?), so the another question is that when my binary "0.1111" can I also write "1.1111x2^-1", why I use here a denormalized notation?